# Name error on shutil and pathlib in cmd prompt

Tags: python, shutil, os.path, pathlib

i am trying to look for a files in directory , copy their entire windows path into a list and copy the those files on the temp folder. 
with the below code i am only able to copy the file name. i have tried using pathlib module but it keeps throwing up a name error when i run it in command prompt . any suggestions would be helpful .

I prefer to use the pathlib and shutil modules , but it doesnt run from command prompt and throws a name error .

Any suggestions would be helpful

```
def searching_all_files(directory):
    dirpath = directory
    #assert(dirpath.is_dir())
    file_list = []
    temp= os.path.abspath(r'C:\Temp')
    for x in os.listdir(dirpath):
        if 'Settlement_Report' in os.path.basename(x):
            s=os.path.basename(x)
            file_list.append(s)
            shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(dirpath,os.path.basename(x)),os.path.join(temp,os.path.basename(x)))
    return file_list 

p=r"some path in single slash format"
path = os.path.abspath(p)
files = searching_all_files(path)
```

error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\WinPython\WinPython 64bit 3.6.2.0Qt5\python-3.6.2.amd64\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", mod_spec)
File "C:\Program Files\WinPython\WinPython 64bit 3.6.2.0Qt5\python-3.6.2.amd64\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Program Files\WinPython\WinPython 64bit 3.6.2.0Qt5\python-3.6.2.amd64\scripts\ptpython.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files\WinPython\WinPython 64bit 3.6.2.0Qt5\python-3.6.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\ptpython\entry_points\run_ptpython.py", line 55, in run
  six.exec_(compile(open(a['<arg>'][0], "rb").read(), a['<arg>'][0], 'exec'))
File "C:\Temp\Load_files_DD.py", line 86, in <module>files = searching_all_files(path)
File "C:\Temp\Load_files_DD.py", line 17, in searching_all_files
shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(dirpath,os.path.basename(x)),os.path.join(temp,
os.path.basename(x)))
NameError: name 'shutil' is not defined
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace of the error message you get.

Comment: @BoarGules i have added in the traceback . please check . Ultimately , i would like to run this though a VBA shell command.

The code works fine when i run this is IDLE .

Comment: did you import shutil in your script?

Comment: @olinox14 yes i have

Comment: You are also expecting that the result `x` from `os.listdir` is a path. It is a basename. To turn it into a path one has to do `x = os.path.join(dirpath, x)`.

Comment: @DanD.i have made that change.